# How to make the links only change color once visited

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding, visited

When I apply the :visited styling after the original styling in my code, the :visited style overrides the default styling which doesn't give the effect that the link has been visited.

The default styling I want is the .btn

The style I want once the link has been visited is the .btn:visited

I have tried moving the :visited styling above and below the :hover style. From what I have read, the :visited style should go above the :hover styles. But it overrides the default styling I want applied to the link the way it sits now.

```
<!-- I want this styling to be the default -->
.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}

<!-- I want this styling to be applied only once visted -->
.btn:visited {
  color: orange;
}


.btn:hover {
  /* Applies to links under the pointer */
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}
```

My expected results is the link has a background of dark grey and the text color of dark red.

The actual result is the link having only the orange text color, which I only want after the link has been visited.

Comment: You mean it overrides the darkred color?

Comment: Yes. The :visited styling overrides the darkred color.

Comment: are you sure its not just orange because you've already tested the link?

Comment: it seems that a browser remembers whether link is visited. try to change the value of `href` attribute and to check colours again

Answer (score 0):

One reason why what you're showing is not working is because `<!-- -->` are not valid CSS comments and entirely break the next rule (because

```
<!-- ... -->
some-selector
```

... doesn't match `some-selector`).

`/* ... */`, however, ***is*** a valid CSS comment:

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css);

/* I want this styling to be the default */
.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}

/* I want this styling to be applied only once visted */
.btn:visited {
  color: orange;
}


.btn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#test">test</a>
```

**Note:** Do not test `:visited` in incognito mode! Because in that mode nothing gets saved in history, hence nothing can be `:visited`.
To properly test this make sure you're ***not*** in incognito mode and clear your cache (browsing history) instead.

---

If your problem is that the browser **does** remember which links you `:visited`, well, that's how it's supposed to work.
If an anchor in the page has a `href` that's present in your browser's history and the `:visited` state is styled (with a specificity above the currently applied style), the `:visited` style will apply. That is the expected behavior. If you want to change the way it works (not recommended), don't style the `:visited` differently and apply a custom class on user interaction.

Example:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('visited');
})
```

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css);

/* I want this styling to be the default */
.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}

/* I want this styling to be applied only once visted */
.visited {
  color: orange;
}


.btn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn" href="#test">test</a>
```